# Is it possible to make an UDP game using only one program (not client and server)?

Tags: c, udp

I have to write, using the UDP IPv4 protocol, a program that allows tic-tac-toe game between two people on different machines.

Comment: It can combine both server and client.

Comment: This is called a peer-to-peer protocol. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer

Comment: It's generally not practical on the Internet, because NAT routers won't allow the initial connection between the two machines unless you manually configure port forwarding.